# React - Why document title does not update for Google Analytics?

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, react-gtm-module

1. I initialized google tag manager by using the below code.

```
import TagManager from 'react-gtm-module';
const tagManagerArgs = {
  gtmId: 'GTM-TLDWCL3'
}

TagManager.initialize(tagManagerArgs);
```

2. I set the page title at every page component by using the below code.

```
document.title="test"
```

When collecting for google tag manager, why document title does not update although the page URL update? Always display first page title.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure custom title in Google Tag Manager tags, i.e. in the Google Analytics tag for pageview setting title as `Field to set` and *test* as its value.